# Adding users or groups of users to an object

Tags: forms, users

I've been asked to come up with an interaction for a page where a '**space**' can be created.

The space will have a name, image etc and an admin can assign users or groups of users to the space.

I see 'user'/'groups of users' as the same thing: they are just another object to be added to the space.

Now, the question: what's the best way to add these entities? I see it as being a bit like the WordPress 'Add tag' pattern but I've just realised this may make **managing long lists difficult**.

[image]

Anyone got any good patterns?

Answer (score 3):

With regards to managing long lists with Wordpress-style Tags, the **... and x more** method is worth considering. Have the list expand when you click the text, and ensure you display the hand cursor on hover.

[image: Tag method with 'more' text]

However, on a couple of projects I've worked on, the Google Docs *Sharing Settings* method has been very effective:

[image: Google Docs Sharing Settings]

This window is displayed when pressing the *Share* button at the top of the page, but in your case *Manage Users* would be suitable.

Displaying it modally in a window provides some benefits displaying Tags alongside your other data:

- Reduces clutter in your interface.
- More room to display information about users/groups.
- Can show the users/groups as a scrollable list.
- Give you space for expansion in the future.

If your users need regular access to the users list, hiding the users in a window isn't ideal. But you could incorporate the Google Docs method into the page rather than putting it in a window.